# guardar datos datagridview en c# en sql server

Tags: c#

estoy guardando datos dentro de un datagridview y al finalizar el usuario debe guardar todos los registros que se encuentren dentro de este en la base de datos pero me da error al convertir una fecha y hora.
específicamente me muestra el siguiente error

"No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido"

[image: formulario]

tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
lblfecha.Text =  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
        lbltiempo.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");



  try
       {
            if ((dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0))
            {
                return;
            }

            string query = "insert into TB_RegistroPeso values (@bin, @peso, @Fecha, @Hora, @Ncontenedor)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexionc.ObtenerConexion());
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bin", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Bin"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Peso", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Peso"].Value));
                //aqui esta el error al pasar la fecha y la hora no reconoce el formato
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha",Convert.ToDateTime (row.Cells["Fecha"].Value));
                //aqui esta el error al pasar la fecha y la hora no reconoce el formato
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Hora"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ncontenedor", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Ncontenedor"].Value));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conexionc.ObtenerConexion().Close();
                MessageBox.Show("ingresado");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {

           MessageBox.Show("error entro en el catch");
        }
```

Comment: Y en que formato viene la fecha?

Comment: fecha = dd/mm/yyyy = 08/45/2019

Comment: hora = HH:mm:ss = 12:45:20

Comment: a si es como aparece en la tabla.

Comment: en que tabla? en que formato lo ingresa el usuario? el error esta en los formatos.

Comment: Quieres guardar la fecha y hora en la que se hizo el registro o tu poner una fecha y hora especifica ?

Comment: guardar la fecha y hora en la que se hizo el registro esta se obtiene de manera automática.

Comment: Ya vi el error que tienes, revisa la fecha que estas poniendo 08/51/2019, por eso te marca que no es formato correcto

Comment: has intentado iterar sobre el modelo de datos de tu `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

Para tu detalle te recomiendo siempre usar la fecha y hora del servidor, ya que al tomarlo del equipo se presta a que no sea la fecha o hora correcta, en tu INSERT utiliza lo siguiente:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) //Solo Fecha

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 8) //Solo Tiempo
```

UPDATE:
Ya vi tu error, lo tienes en la parte de la fecha

```
lblfecha.Text =  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

y lo correcto es

```
lblfecha.Text =  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: el problema es que no se guarda al registro de inmediato si no que se capturan los datos durante 20 minutos dentro de la datagridview y cuando el despachador(usuario) termino su trabajo se envían todos los registros a la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

en c# tienes una propiedad para los datos tipo datetime y para obtener solo la fecha puedes hacer esto:

```
solo fecha
TuVariableDateTime.ToShortDateString();

solo hora
TuVariableDateTime.ToShortTimeString();
```